# Max character length for serialization of folder path

Tags: c++

I search stackoverflow for the answer but can't get a close match. I am serializing contents of a drive. I am using boost::filesystem::path for the manipulation. What should be the maximum ( 300 is just nominal) char length to store the path information in windows OS.

```
struct raw_event 
{   
    friend std::ifstream& operator >> (std::ifstream& infile, raw_event& raw);
    friend std::ofstream& operator << (std::ofstream& outfile, raw_event& raw);
private:

        char path_[300];
       //
 };
```

Comment: What operating system is being targeted? And why not use a `std::string`?

Comment: @user4581301: Windows OS. I am using std::string but for serialization prefer to use POD to avoid garbage

Comment: Windows maximum path is 260, unless you're using the Unicode API. Then it is 32767. Not sure what Boost uses, but always allocating 32k seems like a sucker bet to me.

Comment: @user4581301: Thats seems like a nice answer to me but I will verify. But how do you store variable length strings in file?

Comment: [From the horse's mouth.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) To do a variable length string, I usually go Pascal style and write the length of the string to the file and then write the string.

Comment: @user4581301: You can write both points as an answer, I will accept it as my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows maximum path is 260, unless you're using the Unicode API. Then it is 32767.  [Source MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) Not sure what Boost uses, but you do not want to always store 32k just to be sure. There are times to nuke the site from orbit. This isn't one of them.

To do a variable length string, I usually go Pascal style and write the length of the string to the file and then write the string, but that is for binary files. For a text file, as suggested by `operator<<` in the question, you are better off using a delimiter like quotes and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).